# C fcntl abstraction function doesn't work

Tags: c, file-io, locking, popen, fcntl

I'm writting an app and its in the specification that I need to lock
a file everytime I write on it (this file will be read for other apps
that other team is working on):

I made the following function:

```
int lock_file (int fd)
{
    if (fd == -1)
        return -1;
    struct flock file_locker;
    file_locker.l_type = F_WRLCK;
    file_locker.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    file_locker.l_start = 0;
    file_locker.l_len = 0; //lock the entire file

    int locked = fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &file_locker);
    if (locked == -1){
        /*handle errors*/
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I can get the 1 return (means everything is ok) but when I made a test case
I could write in the locked file Oo

the test code was:

```
char *file = "lock_test_ok";
int fd = open(file, O_RDWR);
int locked = lock_file(fd);
/* call popen and try write 'ERROR' in the file */

/* if the file contains ERROR, than fail */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locking in Unix is advisory: only programs testing the lock will not write in it.  (Some offers mandatory locking, but not that way.  It usually involves setting up special properties on the locked file.)

Comment: ok, I didn't know that. I'll just have to try to talk to the other team and tell than to always try to lock before using the file. tks.

Answer (score 2):

The lock is released when the first process exists and its file descriptors are all closed.

**Edit:**  I think I misunderstood the test scenario -- a `popen()` call won't be following the locking protocol (which is only advisory, and not enforced by the OS), so the write occurs even if the process that called `lock_file()` still exists and is holding the lock.

Comment: While correct, the problem here is likely that locks are advisory, as AProgrammer mentions.

Comment: @nos:  Taking a closer look at the OP's example, I agree with you.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jim said, `fcntl` locks are *advisory*.  They do *not* prevent anyone from opening and writing to the file.  The only thing they do is prevent other processes from acquiring their own `fcntl` locks.

If you control all writers to the file, this is fine, because you can just have every writer try to lock the file first.  Otherwise you're hosed.  Unix does not offer any "mandatory" locks (locks that cause `open` or `write` to fail).

Comment: open wouldn't fail, but block. At least that is what the opportunistic locks smbd creates do.

Comment: smbd does not use standard `fcntl` locks for that. AFAIK it uses a nonstandard API that is not only specific to Linux, but is *specific to smbd* (as in, it was added to the Linux kernel for smbd's sake, and it may not be possible to use that API safely if you aren't smbd). The OP's code behaves as I described.